# MVC 3 Task Wait

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, task

I am working on an mvc3 project, which is using an external sdk that is making asynchronous calls. I have tried the following code, but it doesn't wait for my task to finish.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var price = 0m;
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                          {
                                              // calculate price for example                                         });
                                          });
        t.Wait();
        ViewBag.price = price;
        return View();
    }
```

When i am debugging the first breakpoint is the setting of price in the ViewBag and after that it gets into the task. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: +1, now you can give credit to person answering your Q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `t.Wait()` call will block the execution of the current action until the task finishes. In your example the task is represented by the anonymous function you wrote. Of course if you have placed some asynchronous code at the place where you put your comment (`// calculate price for example`) which returns immediately there's not much point in using tasks and waiting.

So I guess that it will all depend on the specific task you are performing there. Bear in mind that it is a very bad practice to block the main thread in an ASP.NET MVC application. I would recommend you taking a look at [`asynchronous controllers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in order to optimize the execution of async tasks in ASP.NET MVC application and take full advantage of I/O Completion Ports so that you are not jeopardizing worked threads.

Here's an example of how such an async controller might look like in your case:

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController 
{
    public void IndexAsync() 
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        sdk.Items().GetAll(items => 
        {
            decimal price = items.Sum(i => i.Price); 
            AsyncManager.Parameters["price"] = price;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        };
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(decimal price) 
    {
        // Oh Dude, please use view models and crap on this ViewBag shit
        ViewBag.price = price;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: More than, there is not much point to start task and immediately wait its completion.

Comment: Yeap, completely agree. That could be catastrophic in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: The code in the anonymous function is as follows:
    price = sdk.Items().GetAll((items)=>{price =items.Sum(  i => i.Price); });
The GetAll method is asynchronous and that's i why i needed to wait for my task to finish.
I've tried the async controller and i'll use it, but i still don't understand why my thread was not blocked with the t.Wait()?

Comment: If the GetAll method is asynchronous then you absolutely do not need any tasks. They will not help you at all. You are making things worst. If the GetAll method doesn't provide you with a mean to wait for its execution to end you could use asynchronous controllers. Please read the link I have provided in my answer. I have also updated my answer to provide you with an example that might get you started.

Comment: Yep, thanks, i've already tried them and it is doing my job,but i just wanted to know why this code doesn't work. The only thing that i can do with the GetAll method is pass the callback function, where i will have my result items

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the GetAll method returns immediately. So when you call .Wait on the task this call returns immediately. Look at my updated example as how asynchronous controllers could be used in your scenario. You would use the `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment` call to initiate the asynchronous operation and then inside the callback Decrement this operation and pass the result in the `AsyncManager.Parameters` dictionary. Notice how the controller action is not split into two with a specific naming convention. Please read the documentation for more details.

Comment: aahhh yes, that was the answer that i was looking for... anyways thanks for the sample